# There is no existing directory storage/logs and its not buildable: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, hosting

I'm having a trouble right now.
I am deploying my laravel project to a subdomain. It works for my other project, but this one will goes error for everything I tried.

*There is no existing directory at "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SolisTimeReport/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied*

From the error I found that the directory mentioned above is no longer available because it is in my local directory.

I'm using Laravel 5.7.8 with PHP 7.2 as default setting at the shared hosting.
I don't get it what to do with it at this point. Please help.

Comment: You may need to create the storage directory manually, and make sure it's owned/writeable by the web server user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being late on this.
You can rapidly do this on your home route before returning the view;

```
\Artisan::call('route:clear');
\Artisan::call('config:clear');
\Artisan::call('cache:clear');
\Artisan::call('config:cache');
```

This should work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give permissions in Linux to apache or www-data to be able to write on that folder.

The folder must have read/write access for the web-server user.

If you are using Mac if I am not wring the user is  _www

```
chown _www /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SolisTimeReport/storage -R
```